# Create list from custom template SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, development, list-template

I am trying to create a list based on a template I have saved.
[image]
Below code should get the list where the name is "ContactList" but I always get the error that a list by that name doesn't exist. (have tried with feature id also)

```
var listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "ContactList");
```

If I loop thorough all of the list templates I only get the "standard" templates back. If I press "Add app" i can see that my template list is there and I am able to add it.

```
clientContext.Load(site, s => s.ListTemplates);
     foreach (var s in site.ListTemplates)
```

How can I add a list based on a existing template by code? Or can this even be done? I have only been able to add a standard "custom list"

Whole code:

```
        var site = clientContext.Web;

        clientContext.Load(site, s => s.ListTemplates);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation
        {
            Title = "ContactTest",
            Description = "ContactTest",
        };

        var listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "ContactList");
        listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
        listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
        site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: use site instead web (  var site = clientContext.Web;)

Comment: @pat Please don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as accepted in case it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create a List using the custom template in Client Object Model. Try creating a custom list definition, and then create list based on this definition.

[More information about Create List using Client Object Model](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-4/)

[MSDN Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4c22ced6-0bf2-485a-b0fa-0a2aea3a5a30/how-to-use-customschemaxml-to-create-list-in-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Answer (score 0):

`GetCustomListTemplates` will help you,

```
private static void CreateListUsingCustomTemplate()
    {
        string passwordText = "****";
        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in passwordText)
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }
        using (var context = new ClientContext("https://***/sites/CollabSite"))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("****.onmicrosoft.com", password);
            // Load the custom templates from site collection 
            ListTemplateCollection templates = context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(context.Web);
            context.Load(templates);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            // Initialize list or library creation info 
            var listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation
            {
                Title = "Test Custom Library",
                Description = "Test Custom Library"
            };

            ListTemplate listTemplate = templates.First(listTemp => listTemp.Name == "TestListTemp");

            listCreationInfo.ListTemplate = listTemplate;
            listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
            listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
            // Add Document Library to site 
            context.Web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Having some problems with `listCreationInfo.ListTemplate = listTemplate;` I cant find `ListTemplate`

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using?